# Dimension of a certain vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, integral-domain

I have an integral domain $R$ with field of fractions $K$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated free module over $R.$ If $M$ has an $R$-basis $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^d$ then is it true that the set $\{1\otimes_R u_i\}_{i=1}^d$ is a $K$-basis of the vector space $V:=K\otimes_RM$?

I can see that the set spans $V$ over $K$ but I'm not sure why it's linearly independent over $K$.

Comment: Nit-pick:  What happened to $F$?  Where did $K$ come from?  This murder mystery has characters just popping into and out of existence.  :-)

Comment: Recall that for a finite dimensional vector space, a spanning set of the right cardinality is linearly independent...

Comment: @EricTowers the proper beginning would have been "Let $F$ be a field; call it $K$"

Comment: @zcn I know that if $V$ has dimension $d$ then the set is a $K$-basis. But this is equivalent to showing it's linearly independent over $K$ isn't it? Am I missing something? Regards

Comment: In fact it suffices to see that $\dim V \ge d$. One way to see this is using the fact that tensor product commutes with direct sum

Comment: Suppose you had a nontrivial linear relation. Take a common denominator ... Or just note that $K\otimes_R R \cong K$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer So if $\sum_{i=1}^d\alpha_i (1\otimes u_i)=0$ where $\alpha_i\in K$, not all zero then $\exists d\in R-{0}$ s.t. $d^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^d(1\otimes a_iu_i)=0$ with $a_i\in R$ not all zero. So $1\otimes (\sum_{i=1}^d a_iu_i)=0$. Does this imply that $\sum_{i=1}^d a_iu_i=0$?

Comment: Since $M$ is a free $R$-module, $1\otimes m = 0$ implies $m = 0$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Is it because $M$ is then $R$-torsion free? Regards

Comment: Yes, @user149343.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$, or Körper as we say in german, then we have 
$K\otimes_R R=K$. Now since $M$ is free, we have $M\simeq \bigoplus_{i=1}^n R$
this means that

$$K\otimes M\simeq \bigoplus_{i=1}^n K\otimes_R R\simeq  \bigoplus_{i=1}^n K$$